# Class 'com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.AuthKt' was compiled incompatible version of Kotlin. version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1

Tags: kotlin

i am having this error

Class 'com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.AuthKt' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle- 
 plugin:2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics- 
gradle:2.5.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle- 
plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // Crashlytics plugin
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they 
 belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

what can i do?
i am new on this so if someone could help me i would appreciate it.

thank you!

Comment: The error is pretty clear. Either compile both classes with Kotlin 1.9, or both with Kotlin 1.7.1

Comment: yes i undertsand, but i don't know how to do it, i am new on this. i would appreciete it if you could help me. thank you

Comment: The Kotlin version should be defined somewhere in your build system, most likely in `build.gradle.kts` files. Google for "gradle set kotlin version" if you need help with that.

Comment: it is buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'

Comment: That is one of many possible options. Getting this right is always a nightmare with Gradle IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Update the Kotlin version to the latest 1.9.10 (as of now).